# How to make Class Based View mixin's dispatch method fire first?

Tags: django, inheritance, mixins, dispatch

I have a Django Class Based View that overrides the `dispatch` method.

I want to add a mixin to this Class Based View.

The mixin also overrides the `dispatch` method.

Is it possible to have the mixins `dispatch` method execute before the Class Based Views custom `dispatch` method? If so, how would I implement this ?

Currently, when I implement my solution, as in the following example, the CustomerCreateView's custom `dispatch` method fires first, which is not what I need.

```py
class MyMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomerCreateView(MyMixin, CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CreateCustomerForm
    title = "Add a New Customer"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyMixin is CustomerCreateView's superclass. So `CustomerCreateView.dispatch` will always be called first. But you can call `MyMixin.dispatch` yourself before running the rest of the method:

```py
class CustomerCreateView(MyMixin, CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CreateCustomerForm
    title = "Add a New Customer"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call MyMixin.dispatch
        response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Do other stuff
        ...
        return response
```

Alternatively, you can rearrange the inheritance:

```py
class MyMixin(LoginRequiredMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Customer
    form_class = CreateCustomerForm
    title = "Add a New Customer"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class CorrectView(MyMixin, CustomerCreateView):
    # MyMixin.dispatch will be called first
```